# A plugin is giving me "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." error

Tags: plugins, database, errors

I noticed this morning that I was logged off from my site. Whenever I tried to access /wp-admin it gave me a "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." error. After an hour of searching, restoring backups and checking database tables in vain, I finally solved the issue by simply renaming my plugins folder; meaning that one of my plugins caused this issue.

My question is: How can I track down the culprit? I think one of the following plugins caused this issue as they have been updated recently, and works by messing with the WP core files and DB tables.

1. Google XML Sitemaps
2. Ithemes Security (AKA Better WP Security)
3. W3 Total Cache

As of now I'm afraid to reactive any of these plugins.

Comment: Rename the folder (back), and activate the plug-ins one by one until the problem recurs. Then you've identified the culprit and can rename their plug-in to deactivate it again. But by the sounds of things you might want to check out... http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/better-wp-security - they've had **a lot** of complaints on this very issue.

Comment: Ah thank you. That must be it, replaced it with Wordfence now.